# Spring boot ManyToMany with counter if exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, many-to-many

I'm working on a Spring Boot shop and I have a ManyToMany relation between a User table and the Products table. When someone is clicking multiple times on the same product the relation is not created because it exists yet. Is it possible to add a counter variable in the user_product table that give me the possibility to get the amount of same relations? I need to add to the cart the products even when someone clicks on the same product multiple times.

Any possibilities or other solutions?
Thanks

Comment: How is your mapping implemented ? List, Set or Map ?

Comment: In the both of the classes I mapped the other model with a Set<>

Comment: The first click creates the relationship - Products -> User, and the second click tries to do the same thing, if I understand you correctly. Can you change the implementation of the click handler to check if mapping exists and if yes - to add one more product to the set that belongs to the user?

Comment: When you click the first time it creates the relationship. On the second click I need to save also a counter. Because when you click two times on a product it add two times that product in the cart. Can I also save the same relationship two times?

Answer (score 0):

For to implement a counter for the Product associated with an User,
in the User entity use,

**Unidirectional Many-to-Many Relationship**

```
@ManyToMany(target=com.package.Product)
@JoinTable(name="user_products")
Map<Product, Integer> products;
```

When a product is added for the 1st time, set the value 1, and increment it when it's added for the subsequent times.

[JPA 2.2 Specification](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf)

Comment: Now i'm using a Set on both sides with a third tables user_products. How can I implement the Map?